# Tabs in Form Module in Drupal 7

Tags: blocks

How to create Tabs in form Module using FORM API in Drupal 7 and enable and disable them

Comment: form module created using Form API

Answer (score 1):

The [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) collection of sample modules includes a sample implementation of vertical tabs in forms.

Comment: How to Enable and Disable Tabs on Load and Button Click

Comment: I suggest [checking the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7) first and then posting a more specific question if you run into problems.